# Giving two separate answers to the same question

Tags: discussion

I have come across some questions that have received two separate answers from one single person. What are your thoughts on this? What I have in mind is that if the answerer has a new answer, then it is the first answer that needs to be edited with a bold "**EDIT:**" to introduce the new input. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second answer has little or no relationship to the first answer (except the author) then I see no need to keep to a strict "one answer per author" regimen.

If the second answer is just a follow-up on the first then, by all means, encourage the author to merge the two.